# PHP MySQL store image locally

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a simple REST api that works with some images, but I've read it's much better to store the images on the local server instead directly in the db. So from what I understand I must save the image locally, get it's path and save it in the db and when I fetch the image I find it by the said path. But I couldn't find anywhere how to actually do it. How do I get the image from post params and save it ? How do I handle GET requests ? Do I return it as base64 ? Never worked with images before, so any advice will help.

Comment: You should show us what you have already tried. We are not here to write code for you. But yes, what you say is correct, you shouldn't store images in the database. If you google `php upload image`, you should find plenty of examples of how to upload an image (though be sure to check out the security of the proposed solutions, there are a lot of unsafe upload scripts out there), and you probably already know how to store strings in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to deliver images via a REST api is to send the client an URL where the image can be downloaded from.

So you have to put the image in some place the webserver can deliver it to the client. This path will be stored in the database and delivered tto the client via the REST answer.

Answer (score 1):

in form use attributes

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

**saving images**

Instead of saving the image data is into your database, choose a directory ( say '`images`' ) and save the image into it with a unique name.
save the names you used into database (name1.jpg,name2.jpg)

**returning images**

when returning the image you return a url from where client can download the image . see this graph api [response](http://graph.facebook.com/stackoverflow) .

```
cover: {
cover_id: 655226244566013,
offset_x: 0,
offset_y: 0,
source: "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10490073_655226244566013_4652385059438071379_o.jpg",
id: "655226244566013"
},
```

*image source is returned as a url from where you can download the image*.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Image table in your database, with `img_id` as primary key.
Add a the path to your image as `img_name` for example.
Store all your images in a specific folder.

Then, use a form for creation, deletion and suppression of your image.